# Unique continuous function with $f(x)=x+\int_0^1 \sin\bigl(2\pi (x-y)\bigr)^2 f(y)\,\mathrm dy$

Tags: calculus, continuity

I am not sure how to proceed on the following problem:

> Prove that there is a unique continuous function $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$, with the property that $f(x)=x+\int_0^1 \sin\bigl(2\pi (x-y)\bigr)^2 f(y)\,\mathrm dy$ for all $x\in [0,1]$.

I would appreciate just a hint :) Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please clarify if you have $\sin(z^2)$ or $(\sin z)^2$. If it's the second case, write is as $\sin^2 z$

Comment: The original problem is written as I have it, but it is the second one I believe (though as you point out, the initial problem may be ambiguous in that respect)

Comment: Hint: Can you relate $f(z)$ to $f(1-z)$?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: using $\sin(A-B)=\sin \, A \cos\, B- \cos \, A \sin \, B%$ and the formulas $\cos^{2}(x)=\frac {1+\cos(2x)} 2$, $\sin^{2}(x)=\frac {1-\cos(2x)} 2$ you can see that if a solution exists it must be of the form $f(x)=x+A\sin (4\pi x)+B \cos (4 \pi x)$. [ This is a Fourier series expansion where $\cos (2\pi nx)$ and $\sin (2\pi mx)$ terms are non-zero only when $n=0$ or $n=2$ and $m=2$]. Now you can compute the coefficients $A$ and $B$ by going back to the integral equation.